# Unique Taxonomy Term Requirement Across Vocabularies

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

I haven't used taxonomies much so I'm hoping for a quick explanation on an issue for a site I'm working on.

Let's say I have two vocabularies.  Portland and Seattle.  In each one I want to have a term called "Services".

Is that not allowed?  I added "Services" to the first vocabulary - but when I attempt to add it to the second - I receive the following error:

```
A taxonomy term with name Services already exists.
```

Shouldn't it be the Vocabulary->Term combination that makes it unique?  Why would the same term in different vocabularies be an issue?

Comment: Normally you can have terms of the same name in different vocabularies.  Depending on how you configure your site, you can even have terms of the same name within the same vocabulary.  So it depends on your settings and if you are using any contrib modules.  You'll need to update your question with more details about how you set up the vocabularies.

Comment: If you have "Portland" and "Seattle" as the names of vocabularies it suggests your information architecture is flawed as these are not *collections* of categories. I'd expect "Portland" to be a content item of type "City" and "Services" to be a vocabulary under which you'd specify the different services that might be provided.